# Assuming the announced $g-2$ experiment αμ discrepancy is mainly because a dark matter candidate, is this a quantum gravity induced effect?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, dark-matter, beyond-the-standard-model, magnetic-moment

The possible effectively extra added vacuum polarization by a dark matter candidate could account for the recently announced anomalous magnetic moment *αμ* measured discrepancy from the theoretical predicted muon value:

[PRL ARTICLE](https://doi.org/10.1103/PhysRevLett.126.141801)

[ZOOM ANOUNCEMENT](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=81PfYnpuOPA)

I am interested to know in the above described case, would the coupling of the dark matter particle to the muon spin be pure gravitational and therefore we have the case where a gravitational frame dragging phenomenon induces indirectly an electromagnetic effect changing the muon's magnetic moment?

OR

does the $g-2$ experiment show and imply that this hypothetical dark matter can directly interact (opposite of what is believed about dark matter interacting only gravitational) also electromagnetically with ordinary matter?

Comment: Another informative lecture about the subject from Chris Polly: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=44guHKaqQ6I

Comment: Here is an interesting video of possible candidate theories for the g-2 muon discrepancy announced at 7 April by Fermilab : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=R189W2337AQ

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/627849/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/628266/2451 and links therein.