# Review of experiment $g-2$ of the muon

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, neutrinos, magnetic-moment, leptons

This week a new development was announced to measure the pressure of the muon magnetic moment and the variation of its result on the theoretical value. The question is: what is the meaning of this discovery? Does it really involve new physics? Or is it possible once again there is a bad understanding of the theorization of the models and there is a false positive like these false of the superluminal neutrinos?

Comment: There are plenty of questions already on this site about the g-2 experiment, in what way are the answers to them not satisfactory?

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anomalous_magnetic_dipole_moment#Muon

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/627849/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/628266/2451 and links therein.

Answer (score 0):

The recent E989 result and the SM theory (see Aoyama, Tatsumi, et al. "The anomalous magnetic moment of the muon in the Standard Model." Physics reports (2020)) differ for 4.2 sigmas. This difference will increase with the results of the other experiment runs if the central value remains unchanged.
The E989 Muon g-2 Experiment is very precise, and every possible source of systematic error has been considered, so given also the fact that the result is compatible with the BNL one, I would say that the discrepancy with the Standard Model comes from something else.
Moreover, the latest theory results (see Borsanyi, Sz, et al. "Leading hadronic contribution to the muon magnetic moment from lattice QCD." Nature (2021): 1-5.) weakens the discrepancy between experiment and theory.

I guess time will tell!