# What could the new physics be if the experimental value of the muon's $g-2$ factor turns out to be truly different from the theoretical value?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model, magnetic-moment

I was really excited to read about a recent experiment at Fermilab. [Here](https://news.fnal.gov/2021/04/first-results-from-fermilabs-muon-g-2-experiment-strengthen-evidence-of-new-physics/) one can read the article. A dicrepency was seen between the calculated value of the muon  $g-2$ factor, in the context of the standard model, and the experimental value. A truly breathtaking experiment! Finally new physics! But what is the new physics? What are the new particles? What is the new force?
Can a substructure of the muon be responsible? Does it **have** to be substructure? What new particles could be involved, if no substructure is involved?

EDIT
What if the value that is found in experiment turns out to be truly different from the theoretical value? I'm already inclined to think that this is already the case, in all my excitment, but I should not, indeed, jump too high too soon. But suppose there comes a point in the future tyhat there is no doubt anymore. IF. What could the new physics be? Like the magnetic moment of the proton showed a value hinting to substructure (three quarks), this could also be the case for the muon. What else could be the case if substructure is not involved?

And now I see the list given below, by @G.Smith...

Comment: https://arxiv.org/search/advanced?advanced=&terms-0-operator=AND&terms-0-term=muon&terms-0-field=title&classification-physics=y&classification-physics_archives=all&classification-include_cross_list=include&date-year=&date-filter_by=date_range&date-from_date=2021-04-07&date-to_date=&date-date_type=submitted_date&abstracts=show&size=50&order=-announced_date_first

Comment: *Finally new physics!* That is a premature conclusion, given that the experiment has not yet achieved the number of standard deviations from theory to be an accepted discovery, and given that some theorists are challenging the currently-accepted theoretical value.

Comment: @G.Smith Im pretty convinced though. Sigma 4.3 seems pretty close and the theoretical value can always be challenged. Of course, new physics is discovered every day., but nevertheless this feels (uhoh)  like a breakthrough..

Comment: In that context, you should see [this question](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/627849)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Muon $g-2$ experiment: is there any theory to explain the results?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/628266/)

Comment: @NiharKarve It seems indeed pretty incredible (as is stated in the question) that the new theoretical calculation comes around the same time as the new experimental results.