# What was the $a_\mu$ value for the Brookhaven muon $g-2$ experiment?

Tags: particle-physics, experimental-physics, quantum-spin, quantum-electrodynamics, magnetic-moment

See title.  I am researching the muon $g-2$ experiments and have found $a_\mu$ values for CERN (1, 2, and 3) and Fermilab, but not Brookhaven.  I would appreciate your help.

Comment: What's wrong with the [WP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muon_g-2#Muon_g%E2%88%922_at_Brookhaven_National_Laboratory) references?

Comment: That works.  I have gotten into a habit of avoiding WP because of unreliable information, but the citation is exactly what I need.  Thank you!

Comment: A solid publication ref can't hurt.

Comment: https://arxiv.org/abs/hep-ex/0602035 Final Report of the Muon E821 Anomalous Magnetic Moment Measurement at BNL

Comment: Related: https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/627849/2451 , https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/628266/2451 and links therein.